# Android: Date/Time Verify

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker, timepicker

I created a datepicker and a time picker that apply the date and time in EditText field.

Now I need to do a check, that the date and time inserted are forward in time than the current date. need accept only the date and time that go into the future...

how do?

Comment: Show us what you've already tried and we'll be happy to help you with your problems.

Comment: If you consolidate both into one `Date` (or `Calendar`) object, you can simply call [`after(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29), passing in another Date object representing 'now'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `Calendar` object to get the current date...

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Then make a `Calendar` for the date entered by the user, probably using something like this...

```
Calendar enteredDate = Calendar.getInstance();
enteredDate.set(Calendar.DATE, dateValue);
enteredDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthValue);
enteredDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, yearValue);
```

Then compare the 2...

```
boolean isAfterToday = enteredDate.after(currentDate);
```

If it is `true`, the entered date is after today's date.

If you need to use time values, specify them in the enteredDate.set() methods - refer to the Java documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: sorry for exposing a ambiguous problems, I tried just that, thanks